# Unique Text Element per Data Driven Page

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, dynamic-text

I'm working with data driven pages and need to create a unique text element on every page.

Each text element you add to a data driven page gets added to every subsequent and previous page.

Is there a way around this?

The workaround I've been using is to create the unique note on each page using Bluebeam after the page has been printed which is obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a field in your DDP extents feature class, something like "PageNote", and then add unique text for each extent polygon. You can leave the record blank if a particular page does not need notes.

Create a text box on your layout and paste the text:

```
<dyn type="page" property="PageNote"/>
```

You can sub "PageNote" for whatever you name the field.

Esri help article on the topic here: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011568

Comment: This is a nice workaround. One problem with this is if you don't need a unique note on a page and leave the dynamic text field <null> it shows up as <EMPTY> on the data-driven-page. To fix this issue edit the dynamic text properties with the following script: <dyn type="page" property="YourFieldThatContainsTheNote"  emptyStr=" " />. This will not show <EMPTY> on the page when have you a <null> field.

Comment: Interesting! Just a note that the "<empty>" text will not show up when you export the map to PDF, so I have never looked into removing it.